# login with curl

Tags: php, curl

I would like to download a book from google books (which I bought regularly) to read it offline (unfortunately this option is not available for my book).
I would like to create me a script that I pull out the pages and then save them in pdf...
I do not think there is anything illegal because I paid ..
I tried using curl, but the page you saw was not authenticated.
I wrote then:

```
function leggiUrl($url,$data){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
$page=leggiUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth", array("Email" => "mia_mail@gmail.com", "Passwd" => "miapassword"));
echo $page;
```

unfortunately shows me the login page of google ... because it does not log in?

Comment: You should probably use cookies... Take a look at `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: @glavic: -1. postfields will happily accept an array of name/value pairs and querify it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of `https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth` you will see a bunch of hidden fields. Google is expecting these fields in order to allow the login. You need to look at using Oauth 2 method of logging into Google, a straight POST won't do it:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2